# Expanding Click Event Listener to all List Items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an event listener to all li elements in a ul. I currently have the code working for the first list item as a proof but I'm not sure how to expand this to the entire list. I've tried several things like delegate(), on() and an each() but I keep coming up empty. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```
(function() {
    var $body = document.body
    , $menu_trigger = $body.getElementsByClassName('menu-trigger')[0]
  , $menu_list_item = $body.getElementsByClassName('menu-list-item')[0];
// , $menu_list_items = $body.getElementsByClassName('menu-list-items');

    if ( typeof $menu_list_item !== 'undefined' ) {
        $menu_list_item.addEventListener('click', function() {
            $body.className = ( $body.className == 'menu-active' )? '' : 'menu-active';
        });
    }

    if ( typeof $menu_trigger !== 'undefined' ) {
        $menu_trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
            $body.className = ( $body.className == 'menu-active' )? '' : 'menu-active';
        });
    }

}).call(this);
```

Comment: that would be better if you posted as answer to your question, but I don't know why did we bother to answer ?

Comment: @marko I appreciate your input but I'm not one to post a question and wait on someone to answer my question. I hit a wall and then decided to post the question. Then I continued to work the problem and had a theory since I know what I had tried should have worked. Sorry if that upsets you

Comment: that's pretty stupid I must say, question should be asked only if you don't succeed to break wall in some time, not using someones precious time to give them to solve your problem which you can solve on your own. And yeah it upsets me because you wasted 5 minutes of my time that you didn't need. So before asking next question please think well about all possible solutions of your problem, and if you don't find any then you can ask the question. That's actually abuse of this site, that makes you a  help vampire.\

Comment: Hope I was clear enough, don't ask question if you don't want answer.

Comment: @marko Maybe if your 5 minutes of  time is so precious you should do something else. I hope that's clear enough. Not to mention your solution didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Oh but I already spent them, before I knew you don't want your question answered. So I politely ask everyone who read this comment, don't answer this mans questions, he will answer them by himself. Thanks.. :)

Comment: I flagged your question for moderator intervention :) and just continue to break site rules.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with solving your own problem - after all, finding solutions to our programming problems is *why* we use and love Stack Overflow. But if you have a solution to your own problem, we expect you to post it as an answer rather than as an edit to your question. That way you can mark your answer accepted and your question will be considered answered by the system. Nothing to do with pissing people off (that's frankly their problem), it's just for the sake of keeping things organized.

Comment: Thanks @boltclock. I'll edit the question and move the solution to an answer later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. For whatever reason it wouldn't work on the ul element class definition, but as soon as I changed the variable to the nav wrapper class definition I had success. Here's the final working code.

```
(function() {
    var $body = document.body
  , $menu_trigger = $body.getElementsByClassName('menu-trigger')[0]
  , $menu_list_items = document.getElementById('slide-menu');


  $menu_list_items.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target.tagName === 'LI'){
        $body.className = ( $body.className == 'menu-active' )? '' : 'menu-active';

      }
  });

    if ( typeof $menu_trigger !== 'undefined' ) {
        $menu_trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
            $body.className = ( $body.className == 'menu-active' )? '' : 'menu-active';
        });
    }

}).call(this);



   <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav id="slide-menu">
        <ul class="menu-list-items">
            <li class="d-label">Children</li>
            <li class="d-label">Vehicles</li>
            <li class="d-label">Travel Expense</li>
            <li class="d-label">Lodging</li>
            <li class="d-label">Dining</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

<!-- Content panel -->
<div id="content">
    <div class="menu-trigger"></div>
    <h1>Proof of concept for menu closure on item click</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex facer assueverit sadipscing cum. Per at error diceret impedit. Te pro wisi scribentur, senserit urbanitas vix eu, viderer discere an vel. Sed unum lobortis suavitate eu, ad nec utroque aliquando.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery then you can use a selector to add a click event to multiple items.

Something like

```
$('.eventClass').on('click', function() {
  doSomething();
});
```

That'll be applied to any elements with the class "eventClass."  You could use other [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) if those would be better.

If you want pure javascript, use [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Answer (score 0):

```js
//wait dom to load
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul > li').click(function(){
     alert($(this).html());
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <ul>
    
    <li> A </li>   
        <li> B </li>   
        <li> C </li>   
      
  </ul>
  
  <div>
    <!-- example of nested -->
    <ul>
       <li> G </li>   
        <li> D </li>   
        <li> F </li>   
      
    </ul>
   
   </div>
 </body>
```

Click on any :) With jquery you just must specify css selctor of targeted elements :)